# .htacess - .html to no-html URL redirect, how should internal links look like?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

On my website I've set a redirect changing URL adress from .html to no-html.
This is part of the .htaccess code:

```
rewriterule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works as it should, eg. "mydomain.com/example-page.html" is now "mydomain.com/example-page".

Shuold my internal links look like:

1)a href="mydomain.com/example-page.html"

or

2)a href="mydomain.com/example-page"

I am concerned about general SEO performance here, any known issues with using the latter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your rules should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

2nd rule makes sure you are not adding `.html` on a directory.

You should keep your link as:

```
a href="mydomain.com/example-page"
```

SEO won't be affected as people with old `.html` links will be redirected to new one with 301 (permanent redirect) and search engines will update their results seeing 301.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain what is the practical difference between your .htaccess code and the one that I provided?

Comment: Actually I did explain that. `2nd rule makes sure you are not adding .html on a directory. And adds `.html` only when that file exists.` My rule won't add `.html` to an invalid file.